# MySQL: select best from each group, but non repeating

Tags: mysql, group-by, unique, distinct

I have to select top record in each category, like

```
ID| Category_Id | Item_Id | Price
1 | 1           | 1       | 10
2 | 1           | 1       | 7
3 | 1           | 2       | 8
4 | 1           | 2       | 5
5 | 2           | 1       | 9
6 | 2           | 1       | 6
7 | 2           | 2       | 3
8 | 2           | 2       | 8
9 | 3           | 1       | 5

SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT * FROM `products` ORDER BY price DESC
) AS r GROUP BY category_id
```

As result I get:

```
ID | CATEGORY_ID | ITEM_ID | PRICE
1  | 1           | 1       | 10
5  | 2           | 1       | 9
9  | 3           | 1       | 5
```

I have to modify a query to return only unique ITEM_IDs. For example, if item 1 was selected for category 1, then it can not be selected for category 2. So next matching item should be selected for it. So I should get:

```
ID | CATEGORY_ID | ITEM_ID | PRICE
1  | 1           | 1       | 10
8  | 2           | 2       | 8
9  | 3           | 1       | 5
```

Category #3 contains only one item #1, and it is used before for category #1. But complexity is that we can not skip any categories. So it must begin using already used item Ids, if no ids left.

Who can help?

**UPD:** Okay, I see it's too complex. May be I can simplify my question, what about select non-repeating item ids, and do not bother about skipped categories? Example:

```
ID | CATEGORY_ID | ITEM_ID | PRICE
1  | 1           | 1       | 10
8  | 2           | 2       | 8
9  | 3           | 1       | 5
```

Comment: Here is an example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1c7f7/1/0 I don't understand how to query expected result, so I have nothing to show as an example of what I tried. Expected result is in last code block in question.

Comment: I think you should expand your sample data to cover the case where category_id 4 has to use item_id 3 because item_id 1 and 2 are already taken by category_id 1 and 2. Oh, and I don't think that it can be easily solved with SQL alone. Consider a solution on application layer.

Comment: A larger dataset and expected outcome sample could assist in this. I think the rule with the item_id's is what is the most unclear. Maybe explain what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Sean Larkin, actually I should make a page with list of categories. Each category should be presented by image of top selling product. But as long as one product may belong to many categories, we getting some similar images in listing. The goal is prevent similar images on page.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you're looking for is possible with (My)SQL. An easy solution though would be to do it in multiple queries. Say you want to have 5 images on your page...

Pseudo code:

```
SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE Price = (SELECT MAX(Price) FROM yourTable);
save category_id and item_id in an array;
save everything else what you need for display anywhere;
loop over the array
   SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE Price = (SELECT MAX(Price) FROM yourTable WHERE category_id NOT IN (/*insert used category_ids here*/) AND item_id NOT IN (/*insert used item_ids here*/));
   save category_id and item_id in an array;
   save everything else what you need for display anywhere;
end loop
present whatever you need on your page
```